# SQL Select Only Rows With Highest Sum Value on a Specific Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I'm dealing with the following data that comes from 2 different tables, example data:

| Production BOM No. | Item No. | Item Description | Total Qty. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 013085 | 003856 | Orange Fabric | 60 |
| 013085 | 003867 | Tan Fabric | 5.3 |
| 013085 | 006604 | Natural Fabric | 4 |
| 013152 | 012670 | Black Fabric | 9.7 |
| 013258 | 003871 | Green Fabric | 7.9 |
| 013258 | 003915 | L.Green Fabric | 17.5 |

The desired result set would return the highest total qty. per production BOM No. as follows:

| Production BOM No. | Item No. | Item Description | Total Qty. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 013085 | 003856 | Orange Fabric | 60 |
| 013152 | 012670 | Black Fabric | 9.7 |
| 013258 | 003915 | L.Green Fabric | 17.5 |

Right now the code looks like this:

```
SELECT
    PBH.[No_],
    PBL.[No_],
    PBL.[Description],
    SUM(PBL.[Quantity]) AS [Total Qty.]
FROM [ProdBOMHeader] PBH
LEFT JOIN [ProdBOMLine] PBL ON PBL.[BOM No_] = PBH.[No_]
LEFT JOIN [Item] I ON I.[No_] = PBL.[No_]
WHERE I.[Fabric] = '1'
GROUP BY PBH.[No_],PBL.[No_],PBL.[Description]
```

I tried utilizing ROW_NUMBER and TOP in some way but that resulted in either too many records still or too few. I think the answer may be to use some kind of SQL Window Function but I'm not sure how to put it together properly.

Also to keep in mind, I will need to use this as a CTE as part of a larger query, so I can't use ORDER BY in any way.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITON BY PBH.[No_] ORDER BY SUM(PBL.[Quantity]) DESC)` then filter that to 1. Side note: your left-join is actually an inner join, due to the `where`

Comment: @Charlieface Okay the code works great and the row numbers are being accurately labeled. But I am struggling a bit to filter them all to only show Row 1. How do I make reference to the Row No. column in the WHERE clause properly?

Comment: It's all in that link. You need to filter on the outside (ie out it in a subquery or CTE), you can't filter on the same level as where you declare it

Comment: @Charlieface Was able to get it working with your clue to change to CTE, thanks so much for your help in resolving this!